# Java class files not getting created in the classes folder

Tags: java

I am compiling a Java program with the command :

```
javac -cp ./classes/ src/com/oracle/tutorial/jdbc/JDBCTutorialUtilities.java
```

But ironically the resulting class file is being created in the same source folder not in the classpath.  So every time after compilation I have to move the class file. Yes, I have specified the package  properly in the source. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
javac -d ./classes/ src/com/oracle/tutorial/jdbc/JDBCTutorialUtilities.java
```

The `-cp` option is for setting classpath, not for specifying the output directory.

```
adarsh$ javac -help
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...] Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
  -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  -Werror                    Terminate compilation if warnings occur
  @<filename>                Read options and filenames from file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the output folder of javac using the -d argument.

Check [here for more details](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/javac-Option-d-Specifying-Output-Directory.html)

Answer (score 0):

you nedd **-d** as a option to javac command

**-d** directory
    Set the destination directory for class files. The destination directory must already exist; javac will not create the destination directory.

```
If **-d** is not specified, javac puts the class file in the same directory as the source file.
```

Note that the directory specified by **-d** is not automatically added to your user class path